# Access to data from Google login, every activity, after logging

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-signin

I own 3 activity, Activity A, B C.
When you start, it checks if necessary permissions are given for android 6+. If everything is ok to be sent to B.
B asks logged in to Google. If it received login pass to C.
My question is how can I do that once received logged google B, C can use the information user id, name, etc.? I must implant the same code from B and C? Or data are stored in cache or how can I do? Or transfer from B to C, by putExtra? but by puExtra would require every Activity transfer necessary information, it's a little tricky I say.

B consists of sample login google android. [This](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java)

C + D + E are activity, using login id from google to differentiate each user. Each user can save in a remote database list, and id extracted from google account, makes every user to be different, being used as a token.
This is why we need the information extracted from contu by Google can be accessed in each activity. How can I do this?

Comment: consider storing needed information into shared preferences

Comment: So I understand that recommendation would be that id save it locally? can not be extracted in each activity? for not save data in memory phone?

Comment: yeah save variable into shared preferences and read it where ever you want?

Comment: I thought so myself, than I was thinking maybe a fellow forum arew another better idea. like a variable that was done to check whether logging in, and to extract directly from Google without having to save local.

Comment: I think its better to save in shared preferences than accessing from google